# Font-face not working but paths are correct

Tags: css, sass, font-face

I'm trying to use Circular font, but for some reason it falls back on "arial"
Here's my 

fonts.css file:

```
/* Light Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
}
/* End Light Font */


/* Normal Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Book.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Book.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Book.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Book.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Book.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Book.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
}
/* End Normal Font */


/* Medium Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Medium.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Medium.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Medium.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Medium.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Medium.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Medium.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 500;
}
/* End Medium Font */


/* Bold Font */
@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Bold.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Bold.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 700;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularWeb";
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Bold.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Bold.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
}
/* End Bold Font */


/* Black Font */
@font-face {
   font-family: "CircularWeb";
   src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Black.eot");
   src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Black.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Black.woff2") format("woff2");
   font-weight: 900;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: "CircularWeb";
   src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Black.eot");
   src: url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Black.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Black.woff2") format("woff2");
   font-weight: 900;
   font-style: italic;
}
/* End Black Font */
```

Here's my SASS to use the font:

```
$font-family-primary: "CircularWeb", Arial, sans-serif;

@media print {
  body, html {
    font-family: "CircularWeb", Arial, sans-serif;
  }
}

*,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  font-family: "CircularWeb", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I've tried multiple different methods for this, but nothing seems to work. Maybe I did them wrong, so I'm open to any and all suggestions. My compiled CSS directory: root/css. My fonts directory: root/fonts

If I go to: mysite.com/fonts/Circular/CircularWeb-Light.eot it saves the font, so I know I'm using the right directory. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I've never added a font from a local directory only from fonts.google)

Comment: Did you use a Webfont Generator?

Comment: You are importing the fonts.css file into the sass before these declarations?

Comment: @sn3ll yes, the fonts.css file gets brought in as one of the first dependencies in the main sass index file

Comment: @Sara no, i manually typed out each version of the font-face

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting steps:

- test it online
- try a different font
- attempt with one font-face declaration
- double check the font file path
- check in the dev tool (f12 in Chrome) to see that the font is being declared on the elements you declared

Comment: The font we used to use was proxima-nova and it worked fine. I've tried with one font-face declaration and sadly still nothing. The font file path is the same as the file path used with proxima-nova minus the /Circular/filename.eot. The dev tools show the "font-family: "CircularWeb", Arial, sans-serif;" but seems to be only applying Arial.

Comment: It's a bit tough to troubleshoot w/out seeing the big picture. Sorry for being captain obvious, but did you also try testing a snippet online as well? It might help to even test with a generated font style like one from font squirrel. One idea I missed was to test w/out "font-weight" & "font-style".